# writing regular expression that selects lines containing a social security number

Tags: regex

ah I doing regular expression in codelab. it's asking me to " Write a regular expression that selects lines containing a social security number (either in pure nine digit form, ddddddddd, or broken up with hyphens in the standard way: ddd-dd-dddd) For this exercise you must surround your solution with double quotes."

I code it but it gives me error saying "Remarks:Problem: ^\d{3}[- ]?\d{2}[- ]?\d{4}$  accepted:87231-6449" How can I code it so I would have xxx-xx-xxxx

```
 "^\\d{3}[- ]?\\d{2}[- ]?\\d{4}$"
```

Comment: nhahtdh, I've tried this version in codelab software just wont accept it keeps saying this                           "RETest1.java:4: error: illegal escape character
                      "^(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{9})$"
                          ^
RETest1.java:4: error: illegal escape character
                      "^(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{9})$"
                                ^

Comment: That was raw regex, you need to escape \ in the String. Check my answer below.

Comment: You have to look in the documentation how to specify a literal string in codelab. In c# for example it is @"....", Python: r'....'. If there is not literal strings, then you can use a escape char /

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex `^\d{3}[- ]?\d{2}[- ]?\d{4}$` allows either hyphen or white space to arbitrarily appear or not appear at the position specified. It doesn't enforce that all hyphens/spaces must be all appear or all not appear.

If you only want to accept the social security in the 2 format above, then you can use this regex:

```
^(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{9})$
```

After adding String escape sequences:

```
"^(\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}|\\d{9})$"
```

Comment: @yulana: They are both the same thing, except that you need to escape \ in literal String when specifying it.

Answer (score 0):

`^\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}$` : All the hyphens are optional.(Allow all the combinations of having or not having hypens)

`^(\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}|\d{9})$` : Only allow with hyphens or without hyphens